# Java Eclipse OS Error

Tags: java, eclipse, operating-system

For some reason, Eclipse  throws a casting compile error (incorrectly) on a line of code when it is being edited on a mac or linux machine, but causes no such problems on a Windows machine running Eclipse. All the versions of Eclipse in question are updated to the most recent versions.

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    a = (me.getLocationOnScreen().x - this.getLocationOnScreen().x) / 50;
    b = (me.getLocationOnScreen().y - this.getLocationOnScreen().y) / 50;
    //System.out.println(b + "," + a);
```

It demands a cast to Component on 'MouseEvent me' for the getLocationOnScreen method, but not only is it not necessary, after you cast it to MouseEvent to satisfy the error it again claims getLocationOnScreen is undefined for a MouseEvent object.  How can these types of errors be ignored or fixed for editors using different OS's?

Comment: Please include the exact error message — your explanation doesn't quite make sense.  `MouseEvent` can't be cast to `Component` (did you mean `ComponentEvent`?) and you mentioned casting to `MouseEvent`, but it already *is* a `MouseEvent`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it is an OS error and not a version mismatch? getLocationOnScreen exists in [Java SE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getLocationOnScreen%28%29), but not [Java SE 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getLocationOnScreen%28%29) (notice the anchor goes nowhere).

Comment: Yes, and this will be affected by the different machine, if you are using a Java 5 VM, the compiler will check only for Java 5 (since it will have only those libraries).

Comment: Thanks, the unix based machines were in fact using the older VM. A manual update of the virtual machine was able to solve the problem.